# Convert Vue component to base64

Tags: vue.js, svg, base64, vue-render-function

I have a library of icons (icon system) in svg. Each svg has his own component inside Vue in the same way as [Sarah Drasner's icon system](https://github.com/sdras/vue-sample-svg-icons).

I want to import an svg into a js library which allow only icon provided with url. I could have a separate svg file, but I want to style dynamically the fill color with my color system.
The only way I've found is to render and encode the component into base64.

I've found a [simple helper for React](https://gist.github.com/kevinweber/3c519c32db6c976e9cbb5565dc3822f1), but I'm struggling to reproduce the idea with Vue, Vue.Compile, Render, etc.